# Issue connecting to GCP Datastore after upgrading AppEngine from golang 1.9 to 1.12

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I am in the process of upgrading my golang AppEngine app from Go v1.9 to Go v1.12.  As part of that, I'm replacing the appengine specific packages for accessing the datastore with the standard GCP datastore client library.

Now when I run my code, any call to get or set data in the datastore hangs with no error.  In a debugging attempt I added a timeout to the context; when the request times out I get the error `"latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: address true: missing port in address"`

I thought it might be an issue with needing to create a service account, so I followed the steps here: [Datastore mode Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-go), but that didn't solve the problem.  I also tried calling `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file google-creds.json` from the command line, but it also seemed to have no effect.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  Here's a snippet of accessing the datastore from the application

```
client, err := datastore.NewClient(tctx, "my-project-id")
if err != nil {
    log.Panic("Error creating datastore client: ", err)
}
q = datastore.NewQuery("Project").Order("-LastUpdated")
_, err := client.GetAll(tctx, q, &projects)
if err != nil {
    log.Panicf("Error getting all projects: %v", err)
    return
}
```

Comment: This may not be the problem, but an application should create a single client and reuse it.   It looks like the application creates a client per request based on the code in the question.  If the application does create a client per request, then the application must close the client.

Comment: thanks for that tip. It didn't address my problem about datastore calls hanging, but it will clean up my code.

Comment: Have you also changed the main() function to remove the appEngine.Main() call and replace it with http.ListenAndServe(..) as documented here - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go112/building-app/ ?

Comment: So, I think the issue was actually a stray, erroneous environment variable that was being set -- `export USE_DATASTORE_EMULATOR=true` -- that I believe was causing the connection error.  I'm not 100% sure, but I think this was the culprit